# Flutter Face Detection

Tags: flutter, camera, face-detection, mlvision

I am trying out the example app for [flutter camera ml vision](https://github.com/rushio-consulting/flutter_camera_ml_vision)
Now what I want to do is take a picture of the face within the bounds of the custom painter only and save as a png.

With the default example the custom painter which is a square with a thick red border shows around the detected face but now what I need help with is taking a picture of the face within that square.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to crop face part from the original image.So use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/image)  library to crop image. So I.m assuming that you have the coordinates value of face as you showing box around face.

Import this [image](https://pub.dev/packages/image) library and use below method to crop image:

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as IMG;

Future<void> cropSquare(String srcFilePath, String destFilePath) async {
  final bytes = await File(srcFilePath).readAsBytes();
  IMG.Image src = IMG.decodeImage(bytes);

  // pass x and y(offset),width, height value of face bounding box you detected
  IMG.Image destImage = IMG.copyCrop(src, x, y, width, height);

  final png = IMG.encodePng(destImage);
  await File(destFilePath).writeAsBytes(png);
}
```